# How to fix error 749 on Gran Turismo 5

Tags: gran-turismo-5, psn

A few months ago I posted a question about the "network incompatibility error 717" issue that was plaguing some of our regular racers: [How to fix "network incompatibility error 717" on GT5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27459/how-to-fix-network-incompatibility-error-717-on-gt5)

This was answered (thank you Tom Wijsman) and people who followed the instructions have never had any problems since.

Recently we've had a bunch of new people start up racing and from the second week on they started encountering "error 749" problems (I am not sure the exact wording of the error but I believe it says something about network incompatibility.) I pointed them to the 717 question but the answer given doesn't seem to have fixed things for them.

Is 749 a different problem? How can they fix it?

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with UPnP (Universal Plug'n'Play), as I know of some other games that rely heavily on this either being on, or off. Perhaps experimenting with turning the feature on or off (depending on what you have) could help? Run -> services.msc [enter] -> Search for "UPnP (something)" and disable/enable it, then try a couple of races, and see if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no definite solutions to this problem, but there are several suggestions online on how to resolve this. I'll note some of them here:

Since the 749 is a network connection error, there are a few things that can be done in your router configuration settings.

1.
Gran Turismo 5 online uses the following ports for communication with game servers.
If you experience problems connecting to online races, you may want to check the status of these ports in your router or firewall to see if they are being blocked or filtered. Your router instruction manual or manufacturer will be able to assist you with opening these ports up.
TCP Ports: 80, 443, 5223, and 10070 - 10080
UDP Ports: 3478, 3479, 3658, 10070, and 50100
Note: Make sure to enable these TCP/UDP ports in BOTH directions and are entered into the TCP and UDP port fields in your router / modem.

2.
In addition, you can try clearing the Playstation 3's cache.

3.
Also, if you are using a wireless connection, try using a cable connection. This has been reported to mitigate the problem for some users.

I hope some of this will help you have a better experience.